# This code is not compiling, what is the problem (Java)

Tags: java

It should return a Set of 6 different integers. Thanks in advance for help

p.s. I'm newbie here, so, I apologise, if I'm asking a question in wrong way.

Code:

```
package net.javavideotutorials.assignment1;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Random;

public class LotteryNumberGenerator {
    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int upperbound = 100;
        int int_random = rand.nextInt(upperbound);       

        Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<Integer>();

        if (a.size() <= 6) {
            a.add(int_random);
        } else {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
```

Comment: While formatting your code I found a missing `}` at the end of the class. How are you compiling the code? Do you use an IDE or a simple editor and the command line for compilation?

Comment: Use  for loop instead of if condition. If condition executes only once.

Comment: Try using vscode or some other ide to help you sort out simple syntax errors.
Also: what error does the compiler show you - this should be a valid hint to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `if` condition and expecting a loop operation.
`if` condition only checks one time and it will provide the output according to the statement true or false operation.

```
if (a.size() <= 6) {
    a.add(int_random);
} else {
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

you can slightly change the logic to match up what you need.

```
while (a.size() <= 6) {
    a.add(int_random);
}
System.out.println(a);
```

Now the loop has formed, but you are missing something again. The random number generation should come inside the loop, otherwise it will be the same random number variable everytime and the HashSet will replace the same value again and again then you will get an endless loop.

so you need to add the random number generation inside the while loop like this.

```
while (a.size() <= 6) {
    int_random = rand.nextInt(upperbound);
    a.add(int_random);
}
System.out.println(a);
```

Now you don't need to define the random number variable above because you are always generating inside the loop before adding the HashSet.

This is the complete code.

```
public class LotteryNumberGenerator {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int upperbound = 100;

        Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<Integer>();

        while (a.size() <= 6) {
            int int_random = rand.nextInt(upperbound);
            a.add(int_random);
        }
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

if you want to set only 6 numbers modify while condition like this. `<=` should be modified to `<`

```
while (a.size() < 6) {
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer. Forgot to change if statement to loop one. But the compiler refers to another trouble : D:\JavaPracticeAssignment1-master\PracticeAssignment1\src\net\javavideotutorials\assignment1\LotteryNumberGenerator.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<Integer>();
                             ^
  symbol:   class HashSet
  location: class LotteryNumberGenerator
1 error

Tool completed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Use loops instead of if condition.  Use this code.

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 6).forEach(i -> a.add(rand.nextInt(upperbound)));
```

Full Code:

```
 Random rand = new Random();
    int upperbound = 100;
    int int_random = rand.nextInt(upperbound);
    Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<Integer>();
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 6).forEach(i -> a.add(rand.nextInt(upperbound)));
    System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write Something like this:-

```
public class LotteryNumberGenerator {
    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int upperbound = 100;
        int int_random = rand.nextInt(upperbound);       

        Set<Integer> a = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for(int i = 1 ; i <= 6 ; i++) {
        a.add(int_random);
         }
        System.out.println(a);
       } }
```